# How do I extract multiple strings which are comma delimited from a log file?

Tags: awk, sed, perl, text-formatting

I need to extract certain strings from a log file although the strings are NOT in a standardized field/column. For example:

```
date="2017-01-03 08:30:02 -0500",fac=f_kernel_ipfilter,area=a_general_area,type=t_attack,pri=p_major,hostname=hostname,category=policy_violation,event="ACL deny",attackip=1.1.1.1,attackzone=internal,app_risk=low,app_categories=remote-admin,netsessid=c550e586ba75a,src_geo=US,srcip=1.1.1.1,srcport=38256,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dst_geo=US,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstport=80,dstzone=external,rule_name=Deny_All,reason="Traffic denied by policy.",application=SSH
```

I want to grab srcip, srczone, protocol, dstip, dstzone,dstport, and rule_name. I currently use a perl lazy match to strip OUT fields I don't want. Is there a way to only grab those 8 strings and the data within the commas like `,dstport=80,` regardless of the position in the log file? many different entries positions for the same data which make this difficult.

Comment: I apologize if the question is not articulated appropriately. It is hard to describe the problem.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you included an example of the *exact* output you would like to get from your input. Do you need everything in the same line? Different lines? Should the commas be included?

Comment: Output all on one line

Comment: srcip=1.1.1.1, srczone=internal, dstip=2.2.2.2, dstzone=external, dstport=53, protocol=UDP, rule_name=Deny_All

Comment: Commas can be included or stripped.

Comment: Our resident expert said it cannot be done in the bourne shell regardless of sed awk or perl but i want to get a second opinion.

Comment: 1) Please *edit* your question to add more information. It is easy to miss and hard to read in the comments. 2) Your resident expert is either no kind of expert at all, or you misunderstood them. What does the shell have to do with awk, sed or perl? This is absolutely possible in *any* of bash, awk sed and perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick'n dirty approach using `perl`:

```
$ perl -F, -lane '@l = grep {/srcip|srczone|protocol|dstip|dstzone|dstport|rule_name/} @F; 
                  print join ",",@l' file 
srcip=1.1.1.1,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstport=80,dstzone=external,rule_name=Deny_All
```

The `-a` makes perl act like awk and split its input lines on the character given by `-F`, saving them as elements of the array `@F`. Then, we `grep` the array and keep elements matching your target words in the array `@l`, and finally print `@l` joined with commas.

Note that this will fail if any of your patterns can be subpatterns (say you have `foo=bar` and `foobar=baz`).

For longer lists of target patterns (assuming you don't want to write an actual script), you could store them in an array and join them with `|` to make the regex for grep. And by adding `\b` around each pattern you protect from matching subpatterns as well. If we also remove the needless temp array, we get:

```
$ perl -F, -lane '
    BEGIN{
     $pat="\\b" . join "\\b|",qw(srcip= srczone= protocol= dstip= dstzone= dstport= rule_name=)
    } print join ",",grep {/$pat/}@F' file 
srcip=1.1.1.1,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstport=80,dstzone=external,rule_name=Deny_All
```

---

> Our resident expert said it cannot be done in the bourne shell regardless of sed awk or [. . .. ]
>   <sub>*From [your commant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334549/how-do-i-extract-multiple-strings-which-are-comma-delimited-from-a-log-file/334551#comment589384_334549)*</sub>

Sorry, but that's patently absurd. Here's one (of many) ways of doing it in each of those tools:

1. Bourne (again) shell. Don't use this, I only show it to demonstrate it is possible.

   ```
   $ pat=(srcip= srczone= protocol= dstip= dstzone= dstport= rule_name=); 
   $ o=""; while IFS=, read -a fields; do 
               for f in "${fields[@]}"; do 
                   for pat in "${pat[@]}"; do 
                       [[ $f =~ $pat ]] && o="$f,$o"
                   done 
               done
              done < file ; echo ${o%,}
   ```
2. Awk

   Save your target patterns in a file:

   ```
   $ cat patterns
   srcip
   srczone
   protocol
   dstip
   dstzone
   dstport
   rule_name
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   $ awk -F, '(NR==FNR){ 
                   pat[$0]++; 
                   next;
               } 
               {
                   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
                       split($i,a,"="); 
                       if(a[1] in pat){
                           printf "%s=%s,",a[1],a[2]
                       }
                   }
                   print ""
               }' patterns file | sed 's/,$//'
   srcip=1.1.1.1,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstport=80,dstzone=external,rule_name=Deny_All
   ```
3. `sed` (and shell)

   ```
   $ pat=(srcip= srczone= protocol= dstip= dstzone= dstport= rule_name=);
   $ for p in ${pat[@]}; do 
       sed -E "s/.*($p[^,]*).*/\1/" file; done | 
           sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
   srcip=1.1.1.1,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstzone=external,dstport=80,rule_name=Deny_All
   ```
4. Bourne shell (or any POSIX shell) + sed (as for 1., don't do this, it's possible but silly)

   ```
   $ set srcip= srczone= protocol= dstip= dstzone= dstport= rule_name=
   $ for f in "$@"; do sed "s/.*\($f[^,]*\).*/\1/" file; done | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
   srcip=1.1.1.1,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstzone=external,dstport=80,rule_name=Deny_All
   ```

Comment: For 5 years i have been stripping out text i didnt need. In 5 minutes you solved it all !!! BOTH commands work flawlessly!!! HAPPY NEW YEAR !!!!

Comment: @Steve heh, glad you liked it :) See updated answer for something to show your "expert". None of these are particularly elegant, mind you, but they are proof of concept to demonstrate that *of course* this is achievable using any of the mentioned tools.

Comment: I may show him, but I don't want to rub his nose in poop for CLEARLY  being wrong. But this is why I signed up on this site as rarely is there text editing that cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v OFS= -v FPAT=',(srcip|srczone|protocol|dstip|dstzone|dstport|rule_name)=[^,]*' -e 'NF > 0 { $1=$1; print }'
```

Here, I'm using a feature specific to GNU `awk`: with the `FPAT` variable, I'm specifying the format of the fields with a regex, so that each part of the line matching the regex is assigned to `$1...$n`. I then assign `$1` to `$1` so that `$0` is rebuilt from scratch using only `$1...$n`.

Comment: Thank you for the input but unfortunately it did not work. I do have a solution already now.

Comment: this was the output date="2017-01-0309:29:18-0500",fac=f_kernel,area=a_nil_area,type=t_netprobe,pri=p_minor,hostname=hostname,event="TCPnetprobe",src_geo=US,srcip=2.2.2.2,srcport=51753,srczone=internal,dstip=1.1.1.1,dstport=4092,protocol=6,interface=2-1,reason="ReceivedaTCPconnectionattemptdestinedforaservicethatthecurrentpolicydoesnotsupport."

Comment: @Steve I do like to propose a solution with `awk` ;-) Sorry that it does not work. Are you sure to use `gawk`? I believe your `awk` doesn't understand the special variable `FPAT`.

Comment: I am VERY NEW with this advanced use of sed and awk. I am using the old bourne shell (not BASH) on BSD and have found conflicts like this before. I have not yet learned about gawk. Thank you very much for the help !!

Comment: This is quite good, but please add an explanation. Especially since you're using obscure GNU-only features like `FPAT`.

Comment: @terdon You are right, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little delayed on this, but would offer a suggestion - this sort of data is quite well suited to `map`ing into a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
#for debugging - can be removed;
use Data::Dumper;

my @fields = qw ( srcip srczone protocol dstip dstzone dstport rule_name );

#read STDIN or files specified on command line (just like grep/sed/awk)
while ( <> ) {

   #split commas
   #then read key-value pairs. 
   my %row = map { m/(.*)=(.*)/ } split /,/;
   #for debugging:
   print Dumper \%row;

   #print fields tab-separated and in order as above. 
   print join "\t", @row{@fields};
}
```

It's slightly harder to oneliner-ify because you've got a list of fields to spell out. But:

```
perl -lane -F, 'BEGIN { @k = qw ( srcip srczone protocol dstip dstzone dstport rule_name ) } %r = map { m/(.*)=(.*)/ } @F; print join "\t", @r{@k}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the regex patterns you want in a file and use egrep.

Your file (we'll call it filters.txt):

```
srcip=(.*?),
srczone=(.*?),
....
```

Your command:

```
grep -Eof filters.txt logfile.txt
```

Comment: I do have a solution now but this is interesting. I am looping through multiple log files grabbing specific strings. So you are saying I should create a file with only the regex of what I need srcip=(.*?),srczone=(.*?),dstip=(.*?),dstzone=(.*?),dstport=(.*?),protocol=(.*?),rule_name(.*?), but then in the grep command, how would I run it against the log file? grep -Eof filters.txt from logfile.txt ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you missed one of the OP's comments: "Output all on one line". Moreover, `grep`'s regex are greedy, did you test your answer?

Comment: should I create the filters.txt regex file and put each regex on one line or individula lines

Comment: like srcip=(.*?),srczone=(.*?),dstip=(.*?),dstzone=(.*?),dstport=‌​(.*?),protocol=(.*?)‌​,rule_name(.*?),  or one on each line ?

Comment: @xhienne extended regex has non-greedy patterns which is what is being used here. That's what the `?` means. Did you test this answer?

Comment: @terdon Yes I did test it and all I got was one single line. I have always thought that non-greedy patterns was specific to the perl regex (`grep --perl-regexp`). Does this answer work for you?

Comment: @xhienne no it doesn't, and I should learn to test before leaving obnoxious comments. Damn. Seems like you're quite right and ERE (or at least the one implemented by grep) doesn't support non-greedy matches. I wrongly assumed you'd missed the `?`. Sorry!

Comment: I tested it and there were no results. My filters.txt file contains only this in case I did it wrong::cat filters.txt
srcip=(.*?),srczone=(.*?),dstip=(.*?),dstzone=(.*?),dstport=....(.*?),protocol=(.*..?)..,rule_name(.*?),

Comment: sorry about the ....'s that was not in my file

Comment: cat filters.txt
srcip=(.*?),srczone=(.*?),dstip=(.*?),dstzone=(.*?),dstport=(.*?),protocol=(.*?),rule_name(.*?),

Comment: @Steve this won't work for you if you don't have access to the GNU tools (please remember to *always* mention your operating system when asking questions here). If you do have GNU grep, you need i) one pattern per line in the `filters.txt`, you seem to have everything in a single line and ii) `grep -Pof` instead of `EoF`.

Comment: @Steve If you put everything on one line like this, you are imposing a specific field order whereas you said in your question that the position of each field is undefined.

Comment: Sorry ...new guy mistake. I am using BSD and the bourne shell (not BASH as BASH does not exist on this box) But thank you for your time. Happy New Year !!!

Comment: @Steve OK, I added a POSIX shell (so bourne shell) solution to my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can use the command `cut`. In your case, you can give it three parameters :

- `-d ','` : This represents the delimiter of your string. In your case, it's the `,`. You can replace the delimiter by what ever you want.
- `-f 4,7,8` : This represents the part of the string that you want to get (separated by comma). In this case, it is the 4th, 7th and the 8th part. You can specify a range using this form `1-8` for example.
- `file.ext` : This is your log file.

## Examples of use

Lets say your log file is `file.log` (very creative name) :

- `cut -d ',' -f 1-5 file.log` : This will give you `date="2017-01-03 08:30:02 -0500" fac=f_kernel_ipfilter,area=a_general_area`
- `cut -d ',' -f 3,5,6 file.log` : This will give you `fac=f_kernel_ipfilter,type=t_attack,pri=p_major`
- `cut -d ',' -f 4 file.log` : This will give you `type=t_attack`

## Note

`cut` will go through all the lines of your file. If you want to skip the lines that doesn't contain the delimiter you specified, use the option `-s`.

Comment: right on, I do have a solution already though. One problem I have is that this log has multiple entries and different positions for many entries so grabbing a static field range wont work. Thank you for the input !!

Comment: Ah, sorry. Apparently I didn't well understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

bash

```
IFS=, read -r -a fields <<< "$date"
results=()
for keyval in "${fields[@]}"; do 
    IFS='=' read -r key value <<< "$keyval"
    case $key in 
        srcip|srczone|protocol|dstip|dstzone|dstport|rule_name) results+=("$keyval")
    esac
done
(IFS=,; echo "${results[*]}")
```

```
srcip=1.1.1.1,srczone=internal,protocol=6,dstip=2.2.2.2,dstport=80,dstzone=external,rule_name=Deny_All
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with only sed

```
sed -r 'h;
s/.*(srcip=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*(srczone=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*(protocol=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*(dstip=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*(dstport=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*(dstzone=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*(rule_name=[^,]*).*/\1/; H; g; 
s/.*\n//M; 
s/\n/,/g;
' file
```